# Excel Vlookup with C#

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to use WorksheetFunction.VLookup but I get the message:

"VLookup method of WorksheetFunction class failed"

my code:

```
Excel.Range xlRange = (Excel.Range)xlWorksheet.get_Range("3:1", "333:20");
label4.Text = xlApp.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("MAF0510530146", xlRange, 7, false);
```

do you have any idea what went wrong?

the input string "MAF0510530146" is in the excel file...

Thanks

Comment: is the syntax to set `xlRange` correct? I am not `c#` expert, but it looks off. Perhaps this  format instead: `xlWorkSheet.get_Range(xlWorkSheet.Cells[FirstRow, FirstColumn], xlWorkSheet.Cells[LastRow, LastColumn]);`?

Comment: yes. i didn't get any incorrect messages on this line. it looks ok...